# Ember checkbox and value

Tags: ember.js

I have checkboxes created in a loop. I set checked to a property name, and want to reach a dynamic value from the checkbox on click. In the property (for key, value) I'm getting the wrong thing - the label of my property instead of the value. Is there a simple way in Ember to get the value out of the checkbox?
Any help is much appreciated.
In HTML:

```
 {{#each url in controllers.application.env.urls}}
   <div>                                

      {{view Ember.Checkbox checked=updateServerList valueBinding="url"}}{{url}}

   </div>
 {{/each}}
```

In javascript:

```
updateServerList:function(key,value)
{        
    if(value!=undefined)
    {    
        console.log("----1 ", key, value);
    }
}.property(''),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, I started actually playing around with this and realized that it was not as simple as I thought. What I ended up doing was just building a custom component rather than working with `Ember.Checkbox`.

In your template:

```
{{#each}}
    {{check-box url=url}}
{{/each}}
```

Component Template:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id="components/check-box">
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=toggleURL}}{{url}}
</script>
```

The component code:

```
App.CheckBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    toggleURL: false,

    logURL: function() {
        console.log(this.url);
        // Do something with the URL
    }.observes('toggleURL')
});
```

Comment: That didn't work for me - I still could not get the url value out.  I ended up modeling out Ember objects instead.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I plugged in the snippets into my files. The logURL observer returns null for this.url. ...I had to model the data I have, then used the observer.

Comment: Interesting. I plugged exactly that into one of my own Ember apps, and it worked as is. I set an array like this as the model: `[{url: 'http://google.com', ... ]` for dummy data. Try adding a `{{url}}` outside to the template call to see if it's actually accessing the url. Also, looking at your example, you will need to use your `each` helper the component defined like I had it.

Comment: Oh, it does work, yes! I think, this is a better solution than what I have! Thank you!